# Why and how did Vishwamitra obtain a Brahmin body?

Tags: ramayana, vishwamitra

What made Vishwamitra burn his old body through penance and obtain a new body. What was the point?

Comment: The how part is too long... this is described in 15 Sargas (51 to 65) of Valmiki Ramayana: Bala Kanda...also obtaining a new body is not described in Ramayana i think..he attained Brahmin hood in the same body is described..

Comment: You can find why part in many posts https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishwamitra

Comment: I am not aware of this story. From a perusal of both Valmiki Ramayana and Srimad  Bhagavata, there is no such story of Vishwamitra burning his original body and obtaining a new one. The staus of Brahmarishi does not imply a Brahmin body, but it is a state of mind of the person who has realized Brahman and has full control over all his senses - indriyas - not just the five physical senses but  also the mind. Please let me know the religious / scriptural works on the basis of which this query is raised - even if it is  from Wikipedia or some such source.

Comment: I had read the story of Sage Viswamitra doing penance for obtaining a NEW BODY in Sri Guru Charitra, which is a pArAyana Text and very popular mainly in Maharashtra and Karnataka.  However, this story was not part of RAMAYANA.@Nishant Mohan.